# Multi-word Bash Script Arguments passed to Detached Screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use a very small bash script to pass commands to a detached screen in Linux.
Currently the screen is detached and I can send commands to the screen using the bash script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$1;
screen -S "detachedscreen" -X stuff $COMMAND`echo -ne '\015'`
```

The problem arises when the argument is more than 1 word.

Adding single quotes or double quotes around the argument does not solve the problem.

When multiple word arguments are sent to the detached screen, it throws the following error.

```
-X: STUFF: invalid option firstArgument
```

How can I send multiple word arguments to bash without throwing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is obscure, but it sounds like your arguments should be properly separated.  If they are shell commands, you can use a semicolon just as well as a newline.  If the receiving program requires newline-separated input, then first of all, you need proper quoting in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$1;
screen -S "detachedscreen" -X stuff "$COMMAND"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

which might as well be refactored into accepting multiple arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S "detachedscreen" -X stuff "$@"$'\015'
```

and of course, you need to pass in newline-separated commands, like

```
yourscript "hello
buy
more
beans"
```

If you would like your script to always paste a newline between arguments, so you can say

```
yourscript hello buy more beans
```

you can accomplish that, too:

```
#!/bin/bash
commands=$(printf '%s\n' "$@")
screen -S "detachedscreen" -X stuff "$commands"$'\015'
```

If every command should have a DOS carriage return, try

```
#!/bin/bash
commands=$(printf '%s\r\n' "$@")
screen -S "detachedscreen" -X stuff "$commands"
```

Now, if you want a string with spaces in it, just quote it

```
yourcommand hello "buy more beans"
```

will send `hello`,  then `buy more beans` on a single line.

Comment: I have both clarified my question for others as well as found that you did answer the question. Changing my bash script to your first suggestion `"$@"$'\015` means that the argument is taken as-is. Thankyou